# Disable headphones external microphone

Tags: audio, hardware, microphone

My headphones have external mic, but the problem is that it doesn't works.

When I catch a call, I have to unplug them for picking up an incoming call.

Are there an ability to force android to use internal microphone?

Comment: Is your device rooted?

Comment: @RahulBasu yes, rooted